# How to intuitively understand the formula for permutation on non-distinct objects?

Tags: permutations

I have clear understanding of permutation but I still can not intuitively understand why in permutation for non-distinct elements we divide number of possible arrangements by the factor of number of non-distinct elements. $n!/(n_1! \times n_2! \times \cdots\times  n_k!)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For every permutation of $AAABC$ there are six permutations of $A_1 A_2 A_3 BC,$ because $6=3!$ is the number of permutations of $A_1 A_2 A_3:$

$$
\begin{array}{c}
\left.
\begin{array}{l}
A_1 A_2 A_3 BC \\
A_1 A_3 A_2 BC \\
A_2 A_1 A_3 BC \\
A_2 A_3 A_1 BC \\
A_3 A_1 A_2 BC \\
A_3 A_2 A_1 BC
\end{array}
\right\} AAABC \\[10pt]
\left.
\begin{array}{l}
A_1 A_2 A_3 CB \\
A_1 A_3 A_2 CB \\
A_2 A_1 A_3 CB \\
A_2 A_3 A_1 CB \\
A_3 A_1 A_2 CB \\
A_3 A_2 A_1 CB
\end{array}
\right\} AAACB \\[10pt]
\left.
\begin{array}{l}
A_1 A_2 B A_3 C \\
A_1 A_3 B A_2 C \\
A_2 A_1 B A_3 C \\
A_2 A_3 B A_1 C \\
A_3 A_1 B A_2 C \\
A_3 A_2 B A_1 C
\end{array}
\right\} AABAC \\
\vdots \\ \vdots \\ \vdots \\ \vdots \\ \vdots \\  \text{etc.}
\end{array}
$$